# Path of constant length in a grid with maximum sum

Tags: c++, backtracking

Problem: Given a grid of size nxm, where each cell in the grid has a value.

What has to be done: Find a path of length 4 such that the sum is maximum of the cells in the path.

Path is defined as a combination of 4 cells such that one cell is adjacent (up, down, left, right) to one cell in the path.

My approach: Values of n and m are very small,(16), so I decided to use backtracking. This is my approach, however, it doesn't run.

Any help?

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector <int> v;
bool vis[16][16];
int grid[16][16];
int n,m,c,s;

void backtrack(int x, int y)
{
    if(x>n-1||y>m-1||x<0||y<0)
        return;
    if(vis[x][y])
        return;

    c++;
    vis[x][y]=true;
    s+=grid[x][y];

    if(c==4)
    {
        v.push_back(s);
        s-=grid[x][y];
        c--;
        vis[x][y]=false;
        return;
    }

    backtrack(x+1,y);
    backtrack(x-1,y);
    backtrack(x,y+1);
    backtrack(x,y-1);

    vis[x][y]=false;
    c--;
    s-=grid[x][y];

}

int main() {
    cin>>n>>m;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            cin>>grid[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {   c=0;
            s=0;
            backtrack(i,j);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
        cout<<v[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Currently I'm just storing the values in the vector and displaying, but nothing is being added.

Comment: So what is your concrete question?

Comment: Is there something wrong with my code/algorithm? and what the error is, so I can learn.

Comment: First of all, you never set n and m. Once you set them, you're actually get the sums as far as I can tell. You just need to store the "paths" with the sum. Other than that I can recommend to use a debugger to step through the code to see what is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that. I was also wondering if this approach is correct? I've been testing it myself, it gives me the correct answer, but I don't have any rigorous test cases or so.